# Fuzzy matching from string candidate list

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, apache-tika, fuzzywuzzy

I've got a list of company names that I am trying to parse from a large number of PDF documents.

I've forced the PDFs through Apache Tika to extract the raw text, and I've got the list of 200 companies read in.

I'm stuck trying to use some combination of FuzzyWuzzy and Spacy to extract the required matches.

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
import spacy
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(strings[1])

companies = []
candidates = []

for ent in doc.ents:
  if ent.label_ == "ORG":
    candidates.append(ent.text)

process.extractBests(company_name, candidates, score_cutoff=80)
```

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Read through the document string
2. Parse for any fuzzy company name
   matches scoring say 80+
3. Return company names that are contained in
   the document and their scores.

Help!

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://support.prodi.gy/t/fuzzy-partial-matching-with-phrasematcher-ner-task/1084/8 There are a few posts with GitHub links to working code combining these two libraries.

Comment: Hey mate, I did see that one but I bounced off it. Am I missing something in how this can be used to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I populated `candidates` -- `mpg` is a Pandas DataFrame:

```
for s in mpg['name'].values: 
    doc = nlp(s) 
    for ent in doc.ents: 
        if ent.label_ == 'ORG': 
            candidates.append(ent.text)
```

Then let's say we have a short list of car data just to test with:

```
candidates = ['buick'
             ,'buick skylark'
             ,'buick estate wagon'
             ,'buick century']
```

The below method uses `fuzz.token_sort_ratio` which is described as "returning a measure of the sequences' similarity between 0 and 100 but sorting the token before comparing." Try out some of the ones partially documented here: https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/issues/137

```
results = {} # dictionary to store results 
companies = ['buick'] # you'll have more companies
for company in companies:
    results[company] = process.extractBests(company,candidates,
                                            scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,
                                            score_cutoff=50)
```

And the results are:

```
In [53]: results                                                                
Out[53]: {'buick': [('buick', 100), 
                    ('buick skylark', 56), 
                    ('buick century', 56)]}
```

In this case using 80 as a cutoff score would work better than 50.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for your response, you can see where I'm going. what if there was multiple criteria for the "buick" spot? can [AAA] be an iterable through a second list?`process.extractBests([AAA],candidates,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,score_cutoff=50)`

Comment: You're welcome. I updated the answer with a loop through the companies. Let me know if that helps out.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll try this when I get home from lunch and will mark as correct if it runs. Good on you.

Comment: No worries. I'll add another part to the answer so you have a good way to store the results.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers, happy to be of assistance.